# Get string after it is changed by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which gets html as a string.

Then imagine I want to replace all link urls with a new one, without having to deal with any regex :

```
function myFunction(html_as_string) {
    $(html_as_string).find('a').each(function() { // yes this actualy works
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://some-other-link.whatever');
    });
}

var html_as_string = '<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="http://bar.com">bar</a>Lorem ipsum.</div>';

myFunction(html_as_string);
```

Ok links' urls are virtualy changed when within the function, but how could I actualy get the new `html_as_string` variable with new urls ?

**EDIT**

It has to work even when there are several tag elements on the same level, eg with adding `<h1>Foo</h1>` behind the above mentioned string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the html into a temporary element, process it, and then use [jQuery's `.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html) to convert the container's children back to an HTML string again:

```
function myFunction(html_as_string) {
    var $container = $("<div />");
    $(html_as_string).appendTo($container);
    $container.find('a').each(function() { // yes this actualy works.
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://some-other-link.whatever');
    });
    return $container.html();
}

var html_as_string = '<h1>Foo</h1><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="http://bar.com">bar</a>Lorem ipsum.</div>';

console.log(myFunction(html_as_string));
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/h9sfdodx/3/

Comment: he wants the variable as return value not the html

Comment: I interpreted "get the new `html_as_string` variable" as meaning "get the new HTML, as a string".

Comment: @ZougenMoriver, yes that was the meaning. Let me check the answers.

Comment: @lapin note the edit - as @Scimonster demonstrated, `outerHTML` needs to be returned rather than the result of `.html()`, in order to keep the outer wrapping `div`. Above is the correct way to access `outerHTML` on a jQuery set.

Comment: Thank you so much, @ZougenMoriver for your complete answer. However it doesn't work when there's two html tag on the same level ! My fault, in the question I wrapped all within a single `div`, when actualy I have several tag on the same level (I thought it would be the same ;( ). See : http://jsfiddle.net/h9sfdodx/2/

Comment: Ok. Answer updated with something that will work in all cases, back to using jQuery's `.html()` method again!

Comment: Thank you so much @ZougenMoriver ! I think it's a really nice _tricky_ answer that works just perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

> how could I actualy get the new html_as_string variable with new urls

Is that what you're looking for ?

```
function myFunction(html_as_string) {
  var t=  $(html_as_string).find('a').each(function() { // yes this actualy works.
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://some-other-link.whatever');
    }).end();

return t; // if you want it as a string use t.html() , else use t.
}
```

Comment: As you know it, the each loop is useless here

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes. Only added the relative part. to return the variable. it might be a minification of the real problem so I only added the relative part

Comment: Yes but in that case I guess that `t` would give me a list of links, don't you think?

Comment: @lapin yes. forgot to `end`

Comment: @lapin your question is unclear and doesnt make much sense too me because obviously you already know the replaced URL

Comment: @A.Wolff he has string which changes urls. now he wants that new string.(or object). he wants to know the whole _new_ replaced string/object.I don't get your point. ( I might be missing something ? )

Comment: @RoyiNamir it looks like you are correct, i just have hard time to understand the question. And really my bad because rereading it, question is quite clear indeed

Comment: Okay. just remember  , for each filter , you need one `end` . ( if you want to go back to square 1. example `$(a).find(...).find(...).css(...).end().end() //back to $(a)`

Comment: Thank you @RoyiNamir ! Actualy I got the same result that with @ZougenMorivier's Answer : not working when two tags are in the same level (not just one wrapping `div`, my bad :( ). See : http://jsfiddle.net/h9sfdodx/2 (different code, but same problem)

Answer (score 0):

Return the outerHTML of the new DOM:

```
function myFunction(html_as_string) {
    html_as_string = $(html_as_string);
    html_as_string.find('a').each(function() { // yes this actualy works.
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://some-other-link.whatever');
    });
    return html_as_string[0].outerHTML;
}

var html_as_string = '<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="http://bar.com">bar</a>Lorem ipsum.</div>';

html_as_string = myFunction(html_as_string);
```

Comment: Ah yes, it needs `outerHTML`! However it's accessed as a property rather than a method, and on the element rather than the jQuery object, e.g. `html_as_string[0].outerHTML;`

Comment: Huh, when i opened the console on this page to check, `outerHTML` was a jQuery function. Must be a plugin.